# CakePHP request params

Tags: cakephp-2.0

difference between `$this->request->params` and `$this->request->data`

I was reading the CakePHP manual on `$this->request->params` and was wondering what the appropriate usage is for each?
Can someone show an example of why it would be important to use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Request** is the default request object used in CakePHP. It centralizes a number of features for interrogating and interacting with request data.**Request** is assigned to $this->request, and is available in Controllers, Views and Helpers. You can also access it in Components by using the controller reference. Some of the duties **CakeRequest** performs include:

Process the GET, POST, and FILES arrays into the data structures

**Request** exposes several interfaces for accessing request parameters. The first uses object properties, the second uses array indexes, and the third uses `$this->request->params`
eg.

```
$this->request->controller;
$this->request['controller'];
$this->request->params['controller'];
```

for further information [see documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you use the `FormHelper` it will show up in `$this->request->data` and if you don't use the `FormHelper` it will show up in `$this->request->params` or `$this->request->params['form']`.